# How to describe a convergent sequence in the railway metric

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Consider $X =\Re ^2 $ with the railway metric d defined as $d(x,y) =  |X_n - X_0| $ if $X_n , X_0, 0 $ are collinear and $d(x,y) = |X_n|+|X_0|$ otherwise.

How can I describe what it means for a sequence $(X_n)$ to converge to a point $X_0 \in \Re $ in a metric space $(\Re ^2, d)$ ??

Comment: NB the $\epsilon$-balls around $0$ are qualitatively different from the those around any other point, so one ought to consider the case $X_0 = 0$ separately from the generic case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\ne 0$, a sequence $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$ if and only if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $n_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that for all $n\ge n_\epsilon$,

- $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$, and
- $x_n$ is on the radial line through $x$.

If $x=0$, just remove the second clause, since railway metric $\epsilon$-balls centred at the origin are identical to Euclidean $\epsilon$-balls centred at the origin.